# Generating a proxy via Reflection.Emit only works when started with Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, reflection.emit

A task at university was to implement a simple proxy generator / interceptor mechanism using Reflection.Emit.
I came up with the following program.

It seems to work just fine inside Visual Studio in debug mode `[F5]` (Debug -> Start Debugging) but crashes most of the time when started without debugging `[Ctrl + F5]` (Debug -> Start Without Debugging).

What is the difference between these two modes? (I **do not** refer to Debug <> Release mode).
The issue occurs on multiple machines/setups (Win XP SP3 32bit and 64bit, Windows 7 32bit).

[Click](http://pastebin.com/1k9kskV2) for pastebin.

```
// The proxy generator; I assume that the error is buried along the lines emitting the IL code
public static class ProxyGenerator
{
    public static T Create<T>(object obj, IInterception interception)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();

        TypeBuilder proxy = DefineProxy(type);

        FieldBuilder wrappedField = DefinePrivateField(proxy, "wrappedObject", type);
        FieldBuilder interceptionField = DefinePrivateField(proxy, "interception", interception.GetType());

        DefineConstructor(proxy, wrappedField, interceptionField);
        DefineInterfaceMethods(type, proxy, wrappedField, interceptionField);

        return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(proxy.CreateType(), obj, interception);
    }

    private static TypeBuilder DefineProxy(Type type)
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName {Name = "GeneratedProxyAssembly"};
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("GeneratedProxyModule");

        return moduleBuilder.DefineType(
            type.Name + "Proxy",
            type.Attributes,
            typeof (object),
            type.GetInterfaces());
    }

    private static FieldBuilder DefinePrivateField(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string fieldName, Type fieldType)
    {
        return typeBuilder.DefineField(fieldName, fieldType, FieldAttributes.Private);
    }

    private static void DefineConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, params FieldBuilder[] parameters)
    {
        ConstructorBuilder ctor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
            MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, parameters.Select(f => f.FieldType).ToArray());

        // Emit constructor
        ILGenerator g = ctor.GetILGenerator();

        // Load "this" pointer and call base constructor
        g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));

        // Store parameters in private fields
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            // Load "this" pointer and parameter and store paramater in private field
            g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1);
            g.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, parameters[i]);
        }

        // Return
        g.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    private static void DefineInterfaceMethods(Type type, TypeBuilder proxy, FieldInfo wrappedField, FieldInfo interceptionField)
    {
        // Loop through all interface methods
        foreach (MethodInfo interfaceMethod in type.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(i => i.GetMethods()))
        {
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(interfaceMethod.Name);

            MethodBuilder methodBuilder = proxy.DefineMethod(
                method.Name,
                method.Attributes,
                method.ReturnType,
                method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());

            // Emit method
            ILGenerator g = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            // Intercept before
            EmitMethodCallOnMember(g, interceptionField, "Before", false);

            // Delegate method call
            EmitMethodCallOnMember(g, wrappedField, method.Name, true);

            // Intercept after
            EmitMethodCallOnMember(g, interceptionField, "After", false);

            // Return
            g.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
    }

    private static void EmitMethodCallOnMember(ILGenerator g, FieldInfo field, string methodName, bool delegateParameters)
    {
        // Load "this" pointer to get address of field
        g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldflda, field);

        MethodInfo method = field.FieldType.GetMethod(methodName);
        if (delegateParameters)
        {
            // Load method parameters
            for (int i = 0; i < method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
            {
                g.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1);
            }
        }

        // Emit call
        g.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
    }
}

// Some infrastructure
public interface IInterception
{
    void Before();
    void After();
}

public class LogInterception : IInterception
{
    public void Before()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before ... ");
    }

    public void After()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("... After");
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    string DoSomething(string s1, string s2);
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public string DoSomething(string s1, string s2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("... doing something ...");
        return s1 + s2;
    }
}

 // The test program, expected output is down below

internal class Program
{
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        var proxy = ProxyGenerator.Create<ITest>(test, new LogInterception());

        Console.WriteLine(test.DoSomething("Hello", " World"));
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.DoSomething("Hello", " World"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Another question: What's the best way to narrow down such issues?
I tried to save the generated assembly to disk and open the resulting dll in Reflector but it appeared to be empty.

As mentioned above, when started in debug mode the program seems to work and prints the following output.

```
... doing something ...
Hello World
----------------------------------------
Before ...
... doing something ...
... After
Hello World
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What exception do you have? Your code works fine with me in both debug and release modes.

Comment: As I mentioned I do not refer to debug or release modes, but rather to 'Start Debugging' and 'Start Without Debugging'.

Comment: Ok. I think I've found the problem. Now I really do not know why it worked in debug mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Try to explicitly set `x86` mode on project settings tab.</s>

I got the fatal exception only when run program in `x64` or `AnyCpu` mode.

Ah, I've got it. Replace `Ldflda` with `Ldfld`. It works fine even without debugger (I just ran .exe).
`Ldflda` is for fields you pass into method as parameters with `ref` or `out` keyword.

Comment: Do you refer to the setting "Platform target"? If you do: `x86` is already selected.

Comment: I just confirmed, that this will make the issue go away on all my available platforms. :) - Thank you sir!